# EmberJS : How to dynamically reload model and template (after an action, ex 'button pressed')

Tags: ember.js

EmberJS version 1.11.3

I have a button that when pressed, sends an Ajax query to my server and returns some data. I would like to refresh the view under this button with the new data each time.

Here's the simplified handlebar template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='query'>
    <form class="form-vertical" {{action "sendQuery" model}}>
        <div class="control-group">
            {{input value=this.totoQuery type="text" placeholder="Enter an SQL query...."}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send ! </button>
    </form>
</script>
```

Here's the controller for that template:

```
App.QueryController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    totoQuery: '',
    actions: {
        sendQuery: function(model, route) {
            var promise = asyncAjax(queryservice + '?query=' + this.totoQuery);
            promise.success(function(data) {
                model=data.entries;
            })
        }
    }
})
```

The Ajax call works fine and the model defined in the route too ( i tested with a dummy model ). However when i try to update the model with :

```
model=data.entries; //The template does not update with it!!! The template still displays the data from the dummy model.
```

I can't modify it with this.set('model',data) because "Undefined function!! this.set"..
My dummy model :

```
App.QueryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [{
            'title': 'A book title like Harry Potter of Fifty Sha... nvm.. '
        }];
    }
});
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!!!

PS: I've been spending way too much time on this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the model inside controller action in the following way:

```
 sendQuery: function() {
        var self = this,
            totoQuery = this.get('totoQuery');
        var promise = asyncAjax(queryservice + '?query=' + totoQuery);
        promise.done(function(data) {
            $.each(data.entries, function (index, entry){
              self.get('model').pushObject(entry);
            });
        })
    }
```

And you do not need to pass model as parameter in action. You can do something like this:

```
  <form class="form-vertical" {{action "sendQuery"}}>
```

The controller automatically inherit the model property. And one thing is, getting model property using `this.totoQuery` will be deprecated in Ember. Instead use `model.totoQuery`.

Comment: 2 things I realized from your reply :



1. It seems that `this.get('model')` does not work in the "success" function of an Ajax promise. I could only speculate that it's because the function is too deeply embedded in the controller. ('Model' dependency doesn't seem to go all the way down). Or else, we get : 
>Uncaught TypeError: this.get is not a function





2. `mod = data.entries` does not refresh/reload the handlebar template. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @LéoL Please see my edited answer. 1st thing is `success`(it is deprecated) doesn't work outside of an ajax function as a callback. You've to use `done`. 2nd thing, since your model returns an array, you've to push new object to it using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling too much, you can also render something from your controller instead of the model directly from the route, that way you can update the variable from controller and would change easily.

```
App.QueryController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryResponse: [],
    totoQuery: '',
    actions: {
        sendQuery: function(model, route) {
            var self = this;
            var promise = asyncAjax(queryservice + '?query=' + this.totoQuery);
            promise.success(function(data) {
            //model=data.entries;
            self.set('queryResponse', data.entries);
        })
    }
})
```

And in your template you can render it directly

```
<ul>
{{#each item in controller.queryResponse}}
    <li>item.name</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: it says `self.set(...)` is not a function. I think dependency doesn't go that deep in the controller.

Comment: This works!! I would give you an up-vote but my points aren't enough to do that... I'll come back when i collect enough fake internet points :D...